# Read-only image viewers for photography clients with starring or rating

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, photos, image-viewer, image-gallery

The [Best image viewers for windows](https://superuser.com/questions/6925/best-image-viewers-for-windows) can crop, rotate, convert, sharpen, etc. the images.  Here I would like suggestions for **read-only viewers**.

I am a photographer and would run this on a laptop for clients to browse, examine, and review the album of my photoshoot with them (and just that album! :) ) and **to pick or star the photos they like**.

(I want this review done immediately *on site*, so that I can do immediate reshoots as needed. So no online services suggestions, please.)

I would prefer programs that are free for commercial use.

Comment: I started a bounty to get suggestions for read-only viewers with a rating or starring capability. Again +1 goes to viewers that are free for commercial use.

Comment: I need the same for my 6year old kid. (no accidental deletes)

Answer (score 1):

[FastPictureViewer.](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/)  It's much quicker than anything else I've tried (especially the free ones) and the Pro version allows things like starring.

Comment: Hi. I started a bounty to get suggestions for read-only viewers with a rating or starring capability. That was part of the original question. Again +1 goes to viewers that are free for commercial use.

Comment: @William C FastPictureViewer is a viewer (not editor), with a rating system (and there is a free version for trial).  Is this not what you asked for?  Are you insisting it be "Free" to award the bounty? If so, perhaps clarify your question to indicate that's a must-have prerequisite for answers to be accepted.

Comment: @techie007: I am not insisting, and I believe my comment I added when I started the bounty is clear with what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, this question is valid here since you are asking a question about a *software* for viewing pictures.

I would go with `Windows Photo Viewer.` This program already comes with `Windows 7` so you don't have to install anything else. You can set it as your default image viewer by following the steps given below:

1. Right clicking on any image (with a format that you want to be associated with the `Windows Photo Viewer` and select `Properties.`
2. Next, click on the `Change` button next to the `Opens with:` label:

   [image]
3. In the dialog that opens up, select `Windows Photo Viewer` and select `OK`:

   [image]

---

Now, lets say you have associated all `.png` files to be opened by Windows Photo Viewer. The next time you are showing the client any `.png` images, just double click on the image and it will be opened within Windows Photo Viewer. Once the image opens you shall see a toolbar at the bottom of the window:

[image]

Click on the round button in the center and it shall open the image in full-screen/slideshow mode. If you right click on the image, you can see a few options to select the speed of the slideshow:

[image]

Personally, I would select `Pause` or just press the <kbd>Space</kbd> on your keyboard to pause the slideshow. Now you can navigate through the images using the <kbd><-</kbd> and <kbd>-></kbd> buttons on your keyboard. This way you can take your time showing the images to the client, in a grand full screen fashion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, the viewer built into Windows is what I use today. The rotate button is destructive though and [not always lossless](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12361/are-windows-photo-viewer-rotations-lossless).

Comment: It is, but the question specifically stated you were looking for a read-only viewer, and not to crop, rotate, sharpen etc.

Comment: True, and so is the delete button. I guess I can create a copy of the entire photoshoot and let them browse that. I appreciate the detailed instructions.

Comment: +1 for the same answer as me with better pictures.

Comment: No problem. If you actually wish to rotate the images yourself before showing it to the client, you can use any of the applications listed [here](http://jpegclub.org/losslessapps.html). However, if you need an application that has a read only mode like Windows Photo Viewer AND supports loss-less rotation, then that's a different question.

Comment: I just tried out [Fast View Image Viewer] (http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm). Seems suitable for your needs. Make sure you go into settings and uncheck `show file name in full screen mode.`

Comment: @Jay: Hi. I started a bounty to get suggestions for read-only viewers with a rating or starring capability. That was part of the original question. Again +1 goes to viewers that are free for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

Try Windows Picture and Fax Viewer, just put all of the items for your current album in one folder and use `preview` on one.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the viewer built into Windows is what I use today.

Comment: Hi. I started a bounty to get suggestions for read-only viewers with a rating or starring capability. That was part of the original question. Again +1 goes to viewers that are free for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) is fast, and for photographers has the benefit that it can display EXIF data from JPEGs. It can also display [RAW images](http://www.irfanview.com/main_formats.htm) - there is a [plugin](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm) for Canon RAW. It has slideshow and thumbnail options but I find it useful to run it full screen and use the [keyboard](http://shortcutkeys.net/irfan-view-keyboard-shortcuts/) to move through the photos.

Interesting article: [Using IrfanView to View, Sort, and Tag Photos](http://cyberkenblog.com/?p=272)

Comment: Does IrfanView have a read-only mode??  That is, where the only allowed actions are view as gallery, next, previous, zoom and star (or possibly non-destructive/non-persistent rotate)?

Comment: It has many [command line options](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/iviewcli.txt) which you could use in a desktop shortcut icon, however I didn't see read-only there - you'd perhaps have to make the folder read-only beforehand (and undo that when needed)

Comment: Sorry, if I'll make the folder read-only, then my question would be already fully answered by [Best image viewers for windows](http://superuser.com/questions/6925/best-image-viewers-for-windows).

Comment: Hi. I started a bounty to get suggestions for read-only viewers with a rating or starring capability. That was part of the original question. Again +1 goes to viewers that are free for commercial use.

Comment: IrfanView is **not** free for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some free image viewers that are not editors :

[Vallen JPegger](http://www.vallen.de/freeware/index.html)
Reads 40 different image file formats, no installation required (can be included with your album)

[Sheilsoft CDview](http://www.sheilsoft.com/software/cdview.htm)
Intended for CDs, it can act as a front-end for an album.

[ImgViewer/32](http://www.arcatapet.com/software/imgv32.cfm)
Can do some image editing, but the toolbar can be hidden.

These products were chosen from among a very much longer list found in this article :
[Free Image Viewers and Browsers for Windows](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/imageviewfreewin/Free_Image_Viewers_and_Browsers_for_Windows.htm)